# iOS: How to determine position of button only once when dragged into specified area

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am developing a math application that lets the user drag coins (UIButton) into a yellow box(UIImageView) that will have a display of the total amount of money in the yellow box. After some help on stack overflow and my own discoveries I have come up with the method below. Basically the problem is that every time I move the coin slightly, the label that displays how much money is in the yellow box increases(Every slight movement of the coin when it is in the yellow box increases the total amount).

I am trying to increment the total amount of the yellow box only once when the coin fully enters the yellow box. If the coin is than dragged out of the yellow box, the total amount is subtracted. I am currently using touch drag inside on all of the coins. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)dragged_out:(id)sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
    {
        UIButton *selected = (UIButton *)sender;    
        selected.center = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];


        if(CGRectContainsRect(yellowBox.frame, selected.frame))
        {
            amountYellowBox += 5;
            totalAmountYellowBox.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Current Amount: %d",amountYellowBox];
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Ryan W

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I did something similar. I only used the touch processing.
May be the example code will help.

Create new empty project.

Add to project "coin.png" (PNG image 32x32 like below).

[image: coin image]

In project create new file named ViewController as subclass of UIViewController without xib.

In AppDelegate.m file remove all and add code below:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
  ViewController *viewController = [ViewController new];
  [_window setRootViewController:viewController];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

In ViewController.m file remove all and add code below:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) int amount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *count;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *coinBox;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
  {
    [[touch view] setCenter:[touch locationInView:[[touch view] superview]]];
  }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
  {
    [[touch view] setCenter:[touch locationInView:[[touch view] superview]]];
  }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
  {
    if(CGRectContainsRect(_coinBox.frame, [touch view].frame))
    {
      _amount += 5;
      _count.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Amount: %d",_amount];
      [[touch view] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self createCoinBox];
  [self createCoins];
}

- (void)createCoinBox
{
  _coinBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 200.0, 80.0, 80.0)];
  [_coinBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
  [[self view] addSubview:_coinBox];
  _count = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 120.0, 32.0)];
  [_count setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
  [_count setText:@"Amount: 0"];
  [[self view] addSubview:_count];
}

- (void)createCoins
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    UIImageView *coin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coin"]];
    CGRect coinFrame = CGRectMake(40.0 * i, 40.0, 32.0, 32.0);
    [coin setFrame:coinFrame];
    [coin setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [[self view] addSubview:coin];
  }
}

@end
```

Run project. And try to drag and drop a coin inside the yellow box and outside it